# vnstats // stats showing large tx amount

Tags: bandwidth, bandwidth-control, bandwidth-measuring

I have installed vnstat 2 days ago; the site got something like 20k+ visits in this time frame.

I can read a rx value of 2.16Gb but a tx value of 61.2Gb. Feels like something's going wrong. How should I interpret this ? Where could such a large amount of data com from ? (images hotlinking maybe, served images for sure, but still it is much more than what I could think of)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't nothing odd here. Your server receives HTTP requests, which are a few hundred bytes long at most.

Meanwhile, the responses sent by the server are HTML pages, image files etc., which are at least a decade larger.

You can have a closer look at HTTP bandwidth usage by running a log analyzer on your web server's access.log.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your message, I understand a bit more what it is about

Comment: this question http://serverfault.com/questions/665941/bandwidth-stats-is-there-a-way-or-tools-calculate-bandwidth-used-by-serving-i is a follow up to this one; in case it has some relevancy